# Questin on algebraic manipulation of exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analytic-functions

i don't understand how we went from the 2nd line to the 3rd line in order to have $\cos x$ and $\sin x$. This is used in order to prove that $\cos z$ is analytic, i know there is easier ways to achieve that but i want to understand this way.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Att.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+ i \sin x$, we have:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{e^{-y}e^{ix}+e^ye^{-ix}}{2}= \frac{e^{-y}(\cos x+i \sin x)+e^y(\cos x- i \sin x )}{2} = \frac{(e^{-y}+e^y)\cos x + i (e^{-y}-e^y)\sin x}{2}
 \end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

For any real $x$, we have that:

$$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x).$$